# Why I am not able to scrape next page after login with beautifulsoup and request?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, request

I am trying to login to a particular site with python code. I am getting `200` as status code but it is not giving me data on the next page. The response URL is the same as the one I am putting in and the HTML response is also of login page, what am I doing wrong. Following is my code

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib
from urllib.request import urlopen
import html2text
import time

with requests.Session() as s:
    #s = requests.Session()
    url = 'https://www.space-track.org/'
    headers = {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0(X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:66.0)Gecko/20100101 Firefox/66.0'}
    login_data = { "identity": "********",
         "password": "******",
         "btnLogin": "LOGIN"
     }
    login_data_extra={"identity": "******", "password": "**********"}
    p = s.get(url + 'auth/login', headers=headers)
   # print(p.text)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(p.content,'html.parser')
    afterpretty = soup.prettify()
    login_data['spacetrack_csrf_token'] = soup.find('input',attrs={'name':'spacetrack_csrf_token'})['value']
   # print(login_data)
   # html = open(p.content).read()
   # print (html2text.html2text(p.text))    

    #login_data['spacetrack_csrf_token'] = soup.find('spacetrack_csrf_token"')
    #print(login_data)
    r = s.post(url+'auth/login',data=login_data,headers=headers,allow_redirects=True)
    print(r.status_code)
    print(r.url)
    print(r.content)

    m = s.get(url, headers=headers,data=login_data_extra)
    #print(m.ue)
    soup2 = BeautifulSoup(m.text,'html.parser')
    afterpretty = soup.prettify()
    print(afterpretty)
```

Thank you :)

Comment: using my answer, let me know if the `csrf` values matched together below or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import requests

URL = 'https://www.space-track.org/auth/login'

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:70.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/70.0'}
data = {
    "identity": "putyours",
    "password": "putyours",
    "btnLogin": "LOGIN"
}

with requests.Session() as s:
    s.get(URL, headers=headers)
    csrf = dict(s.cookies)['spacetrack_csrf_cookie']
    data['spacetrack_csrf_token'] = csrf
    print(data['spacetrack_csrf_token'])
    test = s.post(URL, headers=headers, data=data)
    csrf1 = test.cookies
    print(csrf1['spacetrack_csrf_cookie'])
```

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way to check whether you are logged in that site is to parse the username. I suppose the following should work. If it prints your username, you can be sure that you are in the right direction. Make sure to fill in the `username` and `password` fields before execution.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import urlopen

main_url = 'https://www.space-track.org/'
login_url = 'https://www.space-track.org/auth/login'

payload = {
    'identity': '',         #put your username here
    'password': '',         #put your password here
    'btnLogin': 'LOGIN'
}

with requests.Session() as s:
    res = s.get(main_url)
    payload['spacetrack_csrf_token'] = res.headers['Set-Cookie'].split(";")[0].split("=")[-1]
    s.post(login_url,data=payload)
    req = s.get(main_url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(req.text,"html.parser")
    username = soup.select_one("#nav-uname").text
    print(username)
```

Comment: Thank you its working, but couldn't get the name, getting some error, but otherwise getting data.